# Implementing find and replace using NPPExec in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, plugins, find-and-replace, nppexec

How do we perform **find and replace** using NPPExec plugin in Notepad++? Any help (command/resource) in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the special requirement that prevents you from using the standard find/replace?

Comment: I am actually trying to a create a SWAP function in NOTEPAD++ where I will have to input two words and they would be swapped using a program without doing the usual three steps find/replace  like `(temp=a;a=b;b=temp)`